# Bulk Insert giving 4684 error, yet column is converted to datetime

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have a table, df:

```
Name    Date

Sally   2019-10-01
```

I have converted the Date column using datetime in Python.
When I try this command in SQL:

```
bulk insert  dbo.Table1         
from 'F:\File1.csv'         
 WITH  (
     FIRSTROW = 2,
     rowterminator='0x0a',
     fieldterminator=',',
     tablock);
```

I am getting the 4864 Level 16 State 1 error, and it is specifically for the Date column. I have researched this for awhile and not sure why I keep getting this error when I've already completed the necessary conversion in Python with this script:

```
  df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
  df.to_csv(r'F:\\File1.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d', index = False)
```

My table in SQL has the Date column as:

```
 date, null
```

Any suggestions is helpful

Comment: What the data length in your table for the date col? And the converted to date in python are they equal?

Comment: Hi it is all the same : 2019-10-01         - yes it is all equal

Comment: Have you Tried the date module instead? Use datetime.date or use datetime in sql. I’m not sure if that is the problem but it can be a caveat from either way.

Comment: I am not familiar with the date module, I  will look this up now. Thanks

Comment: Or format the date in pandas, and see if that can be any help

Comment: Ok yes, I formatted the date in pandas and am getting this error

Comment: Import datetime as dt 

Df[”date”] = df[”date”].astype(”datetime64[ns]).dt.date() sorry i’m on my phone. But rewrite the code of Their is typos

Comment: Ok thnk you let me try this

Comment: Get rid of a backslash in your filename in python if you use r””

Comment: ok, get rid of: bulk insert  dbo.Table1         
from 'F:\File1.csv'       , so it should be: 'F: File1.csv'?

Comment: df.to_csv(r'F:\File1.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d', index = False) : in the python script

Comment: I will try this thanks

Comment: Is the fieldterminator correct? It does not look like comma in the example given...